# Почему в golang не очищается память при работе со слайсами?

Tags: golang

Начал недавно изучать golang и столкнулся с не совсем понятным для меня поведением слайсом структур.
Вот к примеру простой код 
    package main

```
import "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"

type user struct {
ID   int
Name string
}

func main() {

findUser()
r := gin.New()
r.Use(gin.Recovery())
r.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
    a := findUser()
    c.JSON(200, gin.H{
        "message": a,
    })
})
r.Run()
}

func findUser() int {
var users []*user
for i := 0; i < 100000; i++ {
    users = append(users, &user{
        ID:   i,
        Name: "ololo",
    })
}
return len(users)
}
```

И каждый раз, когда я захожу на localhost:8080/ping то сильно увеличивается объем использования озу, который по хорошему должен очищаться ос временем, но это не происходит. Кто знает как с этим бороться?

Comment: Какими инструментами пользовались, чтоб понять, что приложение каждый раз использует память и не освобождает? Сколько делали запросов к приложению, чтоб понять, что при каждом запросе используемая память увеличивается? Пробовал ваш пример, после пару раз обновление страницы увеличение потребление памяти не заметил

Comment: Запускайте с `GODEBUG=gctrace=1` и смотрите вывод.

Comment: пользовался loadtest. Смотрел на возрастание памяти через htop. после 1000 запросов потребление памяти возрастала на 1 гб в среднем и потом не чистилась